# Django global variable based on user groups

Tags: django

In my Django project I have a database that is populated from outside Django, but needs the Django functionality to display data in the database in a user friendly manner. The legacy database structure is as follows:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
#some fields
group_access = models.ForeignKey(AccessGroup,on_delete=models.CASCADE()

class AccessGroup(models.Model):
group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The users have a custom User profile with manytomany relationship with group names assigned to the specific user:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
#some values
     projects = models.ManyToManyField(AccessGroup)
```

Currently I am able to display data from all groups a user has access to, but what I am looking for is a way to create a drop down menu so that users can switch between groups without the need to log out or reenter group on every view.

Comment: Hey, when you say dropdown are you talking about in your Django admin?

Comment: I am talking about Django user from templates not Django admin, users do not need access to the Admin in my case, because they only need to browse and filter the data, not edit or update it.

Comment: Did you work it out?

Comment: Yes, thank you all, I will post the solution I came up with tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
AccessGroup.objects.filter(CustomUser__pk=1)
```

Or

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(AccessGroup__group_name='GropName')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Yes, both ways work perfectly, but what I am interested in is how to get the global variable in the drop down in Django. I might have not been clear, but what Django documentation is pretty scarce about is any global variable that is not limited to one view. It is easy to use request.User or datetime.now(), but anything user specific is very scarcely documented. I imagine that the logged in user is a variable set somewhere, thus I want to see if I can create something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the django user model, somthing like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(AccessGroup)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, unique=False)

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    #some fields
    group_access = models.ForeignKey(AccessGroup,on_delete=models.CASCADE()

class AccessGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

then something like this to get the data in your view

```
def index(request):
    AccessGroup.objects.filter(user__id=persion(request.user).id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know how to get the list of groups, and are just looking as to how to get this list into templates. If not, let me know and I'll explain that as well.

If you're trying to get a global variable into templates, there are really 3 main options:

1. Make a custom template tag that takes the current user as input, and generates this list as output.
2. Use Middleware to generate the list, and append it to the current context for each request
3. Use a method on your user class, or a mixin of it (really easy if you use a custom user class), and just call that method as user.method in your templates. Remember to exclude parentheses from the method call (only in templates), and keep in mind that this method shouldn't accept any parameters other than self.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for getting me on the right track. What I ended up doing is writing a context processor for checking the user permissions:

```
#context_processors.py
def check_groups(request):
    group_check = AccessGroup.objects.values('id','group_name').filter(projects=request.user.id)
    return {
        'group_check': group_check, 
        }
```

Afterwards I created a Bootstrap-select dropdown in my base.html

```
                    <select class="selecpicker">
                        <optgroup>
                        <option data-hidden="true">Choose group</option>
                        {% for grpup in group_check %}
                            <option val="group.id">{{ group.group_name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
</optgroup>
```

And the it is just a matter of users using it as means to switch access groups in views and passing the value via ajax to any other template views I come across.
Not the 100% what I was looking for, but it works and my users are happy.